# square root of a number with display of four decimal numbers Python

Tags: python

I had a homework in which I had to calculate the square root of the input numbers with the display of four numbers after the decimal point.
for example
the input is
4(the number of numbers that the user wants to calculate their square root)
1,
2,
19,
100
and their output is
1.0000,
1.4142,
4.3588,
10.0000
I wrote the program below but I got 0. Can you please tell me what is wrong with it?

```
import math
numberss=[]
sqrtlist=[]
tedad=int(input())
for i in range(tedad):
    addad=float(input())
    numberss.append(addad)
for item in numberss:
    sqrtlist.append(math.sqrt(item))
for sqrrs in sqrtlist:
    print(format(sqrrs,".4f"))
```

Comment: Your program will print the right answers, but you may be expected to write code that does something other than print the values. For example, you may be expected to return the list of values. Double check the instructions to see if code that "knows" the answer is still doing what you were asked to do.

Comment: Your program works perfectly. Please update your question with the text of a session where you tried the program.

Comment: If I was marking your code (which I'm not) I would be downgrading it due to you not validating any of the input. Also, don't use *format()* even though it works. Preference would be f-strings

Comment: @philosofool no, I can send you a copy of what the site showed me as a wrong answer.

Comment: @Vlad I'm new to Python and I came across format() when I searched the ways to display decimals. I don't understand what you mean by "not validating any of the input".

Comment: Don't bother with such things yet. You haven't shown how your program prints `0` yet.

Comment: At the first input try entering a string and see what happens

Answer (score 2):

Your code works perfectly. Perhaps you are entering incorrect values into the terminal. Nevertheless, optimisations can be made in your code:

```
import math

sqrtlist=[]
tedad=int(input())

for i in range(tedad):
    sqrtlist.append(math.sqrt(float(input())))

for sqrrs in sqrtlist:
    print(format(sqrrs,".4f"))
```

Answer (score 2):

input numbers separated by space e.g.: 1 2 4 5

```
inp_nums = list(map(int, input().split())) 

for num in inp_nums:
    print(f'{num ** 0.5:.4f}')
```

result:

```
1.0000
1.4142
2.0000
2.2361
```

Comment: The answer must be displayed vertically and not as a list.

Comment: it is fixed to output as desired now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate the input of the item count as an integer then the individual values as float. You can write a simple function that can handle both cases.

Construct a list of the N input values.

You can then unpack a generator to get the output as required.

```
def getvalue(prompt, converter):
    while True:
        try:
            return converter(input(prompt))
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
# get the item counter
N = getvalue('How many values do you want to enter? ', int)
# build length N list
values = [getvalue('Enter a value: ', float) for _ in range(N)]
# generate the output strings
print(*(f'The square root of {v} is {v**0.5:.4f}' for v in values), sep='\n')
```

**Terminal:**

```
How many values do you want to enter? 4
Enter a value: 1
Enter a value: 2
Enter a value: 19
Enter a value: 100
The square root of 1.0 is 1.0000
The square root of 2.0 is 1.4142
The square root of 19.0 is 4.3589
The square root of 100.0 is 10.0000
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can also get the square root of numbers up to four decimal places.

```
import math
vorodi = int(input())
x = []
for i in range(vorodi):
    i = int(input())
    x.append(math.sqrt(i))
for a in x:
    print(format(a,".4f"))
```

Comment: What is `vorodi`? Stack Overflow is an English-language website. It's clearer if variable names are in English, too.